# how to use photoview 2.0.0 in android studio 3

Tags: casting, photo, photo-gallery, android-photoview

I have a problem with photoview lib from gihub... How can I cast my image to the photoview? I have a error in .java file and no more ...!!!

[image]

and it is a image of my XML file

[image]

Comment: Please post the code instead and not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put it inside in `onCreate` and not outside.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
   super.onCreate(bundle);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   PhotoView view = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
   view.setImageResource( your-image-here );
}
```

Comment: many thanks .... i start programing just for about one month ... my question was very ....!!!  thanks again